# A set with co-dimension less continuum

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, dimension-theory-algebra

Define the ***dimension*** of a vector space to be the cardinality of any basis for the vector space. Also every subspace $S$ of $\mathbb R$ also has a [codimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codimension), which is the dimension of $\mathbb{R}/S$, or equivalently the dimension of any complementary subspace to $S$. My question is not hard, let $S$ be a linear independent subset of $\mathbb R.$ I want to consider two cases:

(1) If $S$ has co-dimension$<|\mathbb R|.$

(2) If $S$ has c0-dimension equal to $|\mathbb R|.$

Is it true for both cases that $S$ would not be a basis, that is, we can not use   Zorn's lemma to extend it to a basis. Or It is just true for (2).

Any help would be appreciated greatly

Comment: I presume you're thinking of $\mathbb{R}$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$? Also, I think you want to talk about the (co)dimension of $span(S)$, not $S$ itself.

Comment: And I don't understand your question itself. "Is it true for both cases that  would not be a basis, that is, we can not use Zorn's lemma to extend it to a basis." Asking whether $S$ is a basis is different from asking whether it can be extended to a basis. And by Zorn's lemma, **every** linearly independent set can be extended to a basis.

Comment: Yes, that's  right

Answer (score 1):

*EDIT: Per the comments below, it seems I misunderstood the question. I've edited my answer accordingly.*

---

Whether or not the codimension is of size continuum isn't the issue: rather, the answer is determined entirely by whether the codimension $codim(span(S))$ is **nonzero**.

The codimension of a subspace $B$ of a vector space $V$ is a measure of the "smallness" of $B$ from the point of view of $V$: the higher the codimension, the more stuff in $V$ that's not in $B$. Now codimension is defined in terms of the **quotient space** $V/B$, but it is still related to the **difference set** $V\setminus B$ (gotta love that notation). Specifically, $codim(B)>0$ iff $B\not=V$:

- Since $V/V$ is the one-element vector space, $B=V$ clearly implies $codim(B)=0$.
- In the other direction, let $a$ be a nonidentity element of $V/B$. This $a$ is an equivalence class of elements of $V$, so let $\hat{a}\in V$ be a representative of $a$. Since $a$ is not the identity in $V/B$ the representative $\hat{a}$ must not be equivalent modulo $B$ to the identity vector of $V$ - that is, we must have $\hat{a}-{\bf 0}_V\not\in B$. But this is just a silly way of saying $\hat{a}\not\in B$. In particular we have $V\setminus B\not=\emptyset$ and so $B\not=V$.

Now beyond that there isn't too tight a relationship between the codimension $codim(B)$ and the size of the difference set $\vert V\setminus B\vert$. For example, let $B_1$ and $B_2$ be $1$- and $2$-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$ as an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space, respectively. Then their codimensions are different (specifically $codim(B_1)=2$ and $codim(B_2)=1$) but the difference sets $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus B_1$ and $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus B_2$ each have cardinality continuum. So the OP is a very special circumstance: we get a connection between the codimension and the difference set only because the question we're asking is particularly "coarse."

Comment: Noah, Schweber, I am assuming axiom of choice and I am working in **ZFC**.  Simply my question is, choose $S$ to be linear independent subset of $\mathbb R$ Ii want to add a condition that ensures that  vector subspace spanned by $S$ is not $\mathbb R$ So, if I assume co-dimension   span$(S)$ is continuum,  Is it  enough, if so how about if I assume co-dimension span$(S)$ less than continuum. Is it still true as well.

Comment: @00GB Being the whole space is the same as having codimension $0$. So $span(S)=\mathbb{R}$ iff $codim(span(S))=0$.

Comment: Noah, Is it still true if  $S$ is algebraically independent

Comment: @00GB (Do you mean *linearly* independent?) Yes - for **any** subspace $B$ we have $codim(B)=0$ iff $B$ is the whole space, directly from the definition. Regardless of what $S$ is, $span(S)$ is a subspace - so $span(S)$ is the whole space iff $codim(span(S))=0$. Just think through the definition of codimension: if it's nonzero then there's some vector not in the subspace, and conversely any vector not in the subspace witnesses that the codimension is at least $1$.

Comment: Thank you very much for this wonderful explanation

Comment: Noah Schweber, I have a question related to the same question here. I added an answer. It si an short argument but need to make correct or not. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4195659/707884